# passing JSTL to a Javascript function using a third javascript file

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

I have a JSP page and I need to use my JSTL parameter in my javascript function.
I know how to pass JSTL to javascript but I want to do it by using the third .js file because my String parameter is a big string and It's so weired to show it hardcoded in JSP page

Suppose ${data} is my data and I want to use it in javascript function which is inside my main JSP file, like this:

```
function x(){
   ....
   doSomeTask(myData);
}
```

which I want this myData come from another javascript somewhere which does have body like this:

```
var myData = ${data}; //this is a different js file, lets say for example alldata.js
```

however this solution won't work as I tested it out !

how can I keep my data separate & call it from my jsp when I'm passing ${data} to that js variable ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create object like `messageMap` in jsp. And create key in this object assign value `${data}`.

In your jsp:

```
messageMap = messageMap || {}
messageMap.Key = ${data}
```

In your javascript file can get the element and append it content to that element:

```
$('.element').html(messageMap.Key)
```